# ssis script component open empty solution

Tags: ssis, script-component

I have a fresh installation of `Visual Studio 2015 Pro Update 2 + SSDT (June 2016)`.

When I attempt to edit C# code of my SSSIS script component (clicking on Edit Script...), VSTA does open without any warning/error but does not display anything (like if VSTA was called without specifying a solution to open).

However I can see the temporary solution is properly created in the background in a subfolder of folder:

> C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\SSIS_SC130...

I can even manually open the solution directly from this folder without any problem.

Any idea why the solution does not automatically open in VSTA ?

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me twice while working in the same environment as you and I hope the outcome for you is different.

**The first time:**

As for me it was that VS had corrupted the Script Component and too bad so sad I couldn't restore it.

**The Second Time:**

Moving the project from machine to machine, at some point there was a change to the .Net assembly of the project. Setting that back to 4.5 allowed me to view my scripts again.

Good luck and enjoy the little surprises VS and SSIS combo like to throw at you